# Can anyone look at my code and see why I only get the [objects MouseEvent] in innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, function

It only works when I have the If-statement alone and not when I add Else-if.

```js
function printResult(description) {
  userPoints++;
  var userInput1 = answer1.value;
  var userInput2 = answer2.value;
  var userInput3 = answer3.value;
  //var userInput4 = answer4.value;
  //var userInput5 = answer5.value;*/

  answer1.value = "";
  answer2.value = "";
  answer3.value = "";
  //answer4.value = "";
  //answer5.value = "";*/

  answerDiv.innerHTML = `
                <article>
                <p>${ description }</p>
                </article>
            `;

  //If/Else som ser om brukeren skrivit in riktigt iht dom korrekta svaren.
  if (userInput1 === correctAnswer1.toLowerCase() &&
    userInput2 === correctAnswer2.toLowerCase() &&
    userInput3 === correctAnswer3.toLowerCase()) {
    printResult("You are a music genious!");
    pointsDiv.innerHTML = `You got ${ userPoints } points. That's a full score!!`;

  } else if (userInput1 === correctAnswer1 || userInput2 === correctAnswer2.toLowerCase() || userInput3 === correctAnswer3.toLowerCase()) {
    printResult("You're not that bad!");
    pointsDiv.innerHTML = `You got ${ userPoints } points.`;

  } else if (userInput1 === correctAnswer1.toLowerCase() && userInput2 === correctAnswer2.toLowerCase() || userInput2 === correctAnswer2.toLowerCase() && userInput3 === correctAnswer3.toLowerCase() || userInput1 === correctAnswer1.toLowerCase() && userInput3 === correctAnswer3.toLowerCase()) {
    printResult("Nice try!");
    pointsDiv.innerHTML = `You got ${ userPoints } points.`;
  }
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS to it  - click edit, scroll down, click "edit above snippet" and paste RELEVANT HTML into the panes

Answer (score 0):

I am  assuming you are passing `printResult()` into the event listener as a reference, like:

```
document.addEventListener(‘click’, printResult)
```

The callback function for an event listener is passed an event object as its first parameter. So you would want the signature of `printResult()` to be this instead:

```
function printResult(e, description) {
  userPoints++;
  var userInput1 = answer1.value;
  var userInput2 = answer2.value;
  ...
}
```

Alternatively you can change the registration of the event listener as follows:

```
document.addEventListener(‘click’, () => printResult(someDiscription))
```

Where `someDiscription` is whatever description you want